# Cakephp and Croogo cross models

Tags: php, cakephp, croogo

I'm using Croogo as main system. And have built a custom plugin for it. let's call it MyPlugin.

Croogo and MyPlugin both have model User.

MyPlugin's controller should use MyPlugin.User class (by default). it's also manually included in $uses array.

Everything works fine on local PC. But on client's server for some reasons it's ignoring MyPlugin.User model and uses Croogo's default User.User model. 
any ideas why and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two classes with the same name in the same namespace.

If you have this:

```
<?php

// App/Model/User.php
class User extends AppModel
```

And this

```
<?php

// Plugins/MyPlugin/Model/User.php
class User extends MyPluginAppModel {
```

It won't work.

You might think it works but what'll happen is that whichever class is loaded first (and also then populates the cache with "this class means that file") is the one that will be used irrespective of which User model you attempt to load/reference. This is also inbuilt into the way the App/ClassRegistry classes work:

```
$x = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$y = ClassRegistry::init('My.User');
$z = ClassRegistry::init('Other.User');

$x === $y === $z
```

The above does *not* mean they are all instances of the class in `app/Model/User.php` - depending on the execution order of the rest of your application code it will be a pseudo random instance of any one of them.

### Solution

The only solution is to use different class names such that there is no name conflict e.g.:

```
<?php

// Plugins/MyPlugin/Model/MyPluginUser.php
class MyPluginUser extends MyPluginAppModel {
```

Note that this doesn't only affect model classes it affects all classes in an application - e.g. [controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460626/duplicate-controller-names-from-different-plugins)